# need to convert UTF8 and UTF16 .csv files to ASCII

Tags: linux, shell, unix, utf-8

I have Script to convert the .csv files which are in UTF8 format to ASCII format. now i wanted to convert the files which are in UTF16 also and if the file is in ASCII keep as is. i am using below code to change the UTF8 and UTF16 separately. help on this to do in a single script.

```
#/bin/bash
for i in *.csv
do 
iconv -c -f  UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 $i -o $i."utf8"
mv $i."utf8" $i
done
```

Thanks

Comment: ISO 8859-1 is not ASCII.

Comment: How do you know which files are UTF-16 and which one are UTF-8?  Or is that part of the question you need an answer to?

Comment: Yes. i need to check the file type. if it is UTF-8 then convert and  if it is UTF-16 then convert else remaining files are in ASCII only so keep as is.

Answer (score 2):

Use `enca` or `file -i` to detect your file's format.

Example:

```
#/bin/bash
for i in *.csv
do
    if [[ $(enca -L none "$i") != *ASCII* ]]; then
        iconv -c -f  UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 "$i" -o "$i.utf8"
        mv "$i.utf8" "$i"
    fi
done
```

Please try it on a test directory with test files first.

For `file -i` I think it could be done as well like:

```
    if [[ $(file -i "$i") != *ascii* ]]; then
```

Comment: i wanted to change UTF-16 files as well

Comment: @Dileep That would change anything but ascii files.

Comment: iconv -f UTF-16 -t ISO-8859-1 sjkdhskjdsdkf.csv>kjhfdjs_iso.csv when i changed like this, the file is  ASCII C++ program text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators. but when i used your code it is showing file as data.

Comment: @Dileep What do you use to detect file type, `enca` or `file -i`? Can you show me what outputs they produce on every type of file so that I could update the code? I mean manually not by the script I provided.

Comment: i am using file only. If i am converting UTF-8 file,  it is converting to ASCII only. but UTF-16 files showing as data file type

Comment: @Dileep Can you try using `enca` instead?